# GetCommTimeouts function failed with error code 50

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port, timeout, createfile

when I develop a PCIe communication interface, I used CreateFile & Readfile function to operate the device. But when I tried to set timeout to the handle, I met the following problem and this is my code,

```
    HANDLE* device;
    char device_path_process[MAX_PATH+1] = "";
    ...
    
    *device = CreateFile(device_path_process, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
    if (*device == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cout<< std::to_string(GetLastError()) << std::endl;
        status = 2;
        goto Exit;
    }
    COMMTIMEOUTS cto;
    if(!GetCommTimeouts(*device, &cto)) {
        std::cout<< std::to_string(GetLastError()) << std::endl;
        status = 3;
        goto Exit;
    }
```

CreateFile function worked normally, but when I want to get its timeout setting, it return error code 50.

Does anyone has ideas? Thanks!

Comment: *The request is not supported.* What can be clearer?

Comment: *I tried to **set** timeout to the handle* Why do you **Get**CommTimeouts?

Comment: Before setting timeout, I get its setting at first, and then found out this problem. Also, SetCommTimeouts didn't work and returned error code 50.

Comment: It may be that the file indicated by "device_path_process" is not a serial port. Or is it because only GENERIC_READ is specified? Why not check the file name or specify GENERIC_WRITE in the CreateFile parameter as well?

Comment: I know ‘*device’ is the handle returned by ‘CreateFile’, but is such a variable legal?

Comment: @kunif I added GENERIC_WRITE to createfile, but it also cannot work.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT I change my code to use HANDLE device, but not HANDLE *device to operate the same work. However, it still return error code 50.

Comment: @Lyon I wrote a minimal sample for testing and found no problems, you can refer to my code.
https://github.com/SchrdingerCAT123/GetCommTimeoutsTest/blob/main/GetCommTimeoutsTest.cpp

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT Tanks. Is it possible that Get/SetCommTimeouts function cannot apply on my device interface? My device interface is Xilinx PCIe, not a UART serial port.

Comment: If this function works on your other ports, it could be a hardware problem.

Comment: Do you have any problems with other COMs tested？

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT other COMs can work with commtimeout successfully. Do you have any suggestion or solution to return (unblocked) from readfile() function immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this problem by changing the setting parameters in driver to achieve the same function as SetCommTimeouts()